# Why dict.get return a tuple with None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict:

```
book = {
'id': 2,
'author': 'J.R.R. Tolkien',
'pages': 332,
'title': 'Fellowship',
}

err_msg='No such key'

a = book.get('signature'),err_msg
print(a)
```

Result is:

> (None, 'No such key')

Why I receive the tuple as a result instead of 'No such key'?

In the documentation:

**get(key[, default])**

*Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.*

Comment: `default` should be an argument of `get`: `book.get('signature', err_msg)`

Comment: typo: change `a = book.get('signature'),err_msg` to `a = book.get('signature',err_msg)`

Answer (score 3):

The `[, default]` goes inside the function call. `book.get('signature', err_msg)`.